# Will MongoDB Go Driver automatically convert ‘uint64’ to bson type? Overflows error returned

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

As the title shows, I have a struct defined an **uint64** field, but error returned when I set its value as **math.MaxUint64**.

This is my code:

```golang
type MyDoc struct {
    Number    uint64 `bson:"_id"`
    Timestamp int64  `bson:"time"`
}

// I just want to know whether uint64 overflows or not.
func main() {
    mydoc := &MyDoc{
        Number: math.MaxUint64,
        Timestamp: time.Now().UnixNano(),
    }

    v, err := bson.Marshal(mydoc)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

After executed, error is following:

```
panic: 18446744073709551615 overflows int64 [recovered]
    panic: 18446744073709551615 overflows int64
```

Obviously, **uint64** types of data are processed as **int64** which is not I expect.

So, how to store an uint64 data but not overflows in MongoDB?? I can not use string type instead, because I need to compare the size of number so that sorts documents.

I am using MongoDB official Go Driver.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom encoder and decoder.

With the code you provided, you could do something like that:

```golang
// define a custom type so you can register custom encoder/decoder for it
type MyNumber uint64

type MyDoc struct {
    Number    MyNumber `bson:"_id"`
    Timestamp int64    `bson:"time"`
}

// create a custom registry builder
rb := bsoncodec.NewRegistryBuilder()

// register default codecs and encoders/decoders
var primitiveCodecs bson.PrimitiveCodecs
bsoncodec.DefaultValueEncoders{}.RegisterDefaultEncoders(rb)
bsoncodec.DefaultValueDecoders{}.RegisterDefaultDecoders(rb)
primitiveCodecs.RegisterPrimitiveCodecs(rb)

// register custom encoder/decoder
myNumberType := reflect.TypeOf(MyNumber(0))

rb.RegisterTypeEncoder(
    myNumberType,
    bsoncodec.ValueEncoderFunc(func(_ bsoncodec.EncodeContext, vw bsonrw.ValueWriter, val reflect.Value) error {
        if !val.IsValid() || val.Type() != myNumberType {
            return bsoncodec.ValueEncoderError{
                Name:     "MyNumberEncodeValue",
                Types:    []reflect.Type{myNumberType},
                Received: val,
            }
        }
        // IMPORTANT STEP: cast uint64 to int64 so it can be stored in mongo
        vw.WriteInt64(int64(val.Uint()))
        return nil
    }),
)

rb.RegisterTypeDecoder(
    myNumberType,
    bsoncodec.ValueDecoderFunc(func(_ bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
        // IMPORTANT STEP: read sore value in mongo as int64
        read, err := vr.ReadInt64()
    if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // IMPORTANT STEP: cast back to uint64
        val.SetUint(uint64(read))
        return nil
    }),
)

// build the registry
reg := rb.Build()
```

To use this custom registry, you can pass it as option when creating your collection

```golang
collection := client.Database("testing").Collection("myCollection", &options.CollectionOptions{
        Registry: reg,
    })
```